# Creating a list of components and their install status in a c# form

Tags: c#, installation

I am creating an installer for some sharepoint addons and want a similar style to installers that list each package in the list and have an icon/text next to each showing its status. This starts at waiting then installed/not installed.

Does anyone know what this is called? Or how to implement it? Surely there is a better way than creating one from scratch?

Example photo at: 
[Example](http://www.mikepalumbo.com/uploads/2009/11/vs2008_installer.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Visual Studio installer was probably created from scratch.  If you want a similar look and feel to that, you will definitely have to create your own.

I would recommend that you instead look at making a custom skin for the [Nullsoft Installer System](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page).

It may be a pain, but you can create custom elements showing progress of individual elements by creating a plug-in.

Comment: Thanks, I hoped there was a template for it as it is a fairly common style. I can't use nullsoft as I need to use a lot of C# to handle installing some complex sharepoint stuff using the object model and cmd line operations.
Thanks